# How to get data for rows that follow certain pattern

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 1 | 1 |
| 23 | 4 | 2 |
| 23 | 56 | 1 |
| 23 | 59 | 2 |
| 15 | 89 | 1 |
| 15 | 12 | 1 |
| 15 | 15 | 2 |
| 17 | 18 | 1 |
| 17 | 21 | 2 |
| 78 | 11 | 1 |
| 78 | 38 | 1 |
| 78 | 41 | 2 |

Now this data has certain pattern on column y and column z.
I want to get all the data where in column z we have a row wise pair of 2 followed by 1 for a given value in x. Simply put, we need to remove all rows that have 1 in column z but that 1 is not followed by 2 in next row.

The final output should look like this:

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 1 | 1 |
| 23 | 4 | 2 |
| 23 | 56 | 1 |
| 23 | 59 | 2 |
| 15 | 12 | 1 |
| 15 | 15 | 2 |
| 17 | 18 | 1 |
| 17 | 21 | 2 |
| 78 | 38 | 1 |
| 78 | 41 | 2 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  filter((((z == 1) & (lead(z) == 2)) | ((z == 2) & (lag(z) == 1))))

# A tibble: 10 × 3
# Groups:   x [4]
       x     y     z
   <int> <int> <int>
 1    23     1     1
 2    23     4     2
 3    23    56     1
 4    23    59     2
 5    15    12     1
 6    15    15     2
 7    17    18     1
 8    17    21     2
 9    78    38     1
10    78    41     2
```

Comment: Just a clarification needed: aren't these 2 conditions saying the same thing. `((z == 1) & (lead(z) == 2))` and `((z == 2) & (lag(z) == 1))` then why apply both the conditions in `filter` function

Comment: Yes indeed, but we need both of them so that we get a `TRUE` value for each 1 followed by 2 and each 2 preceded by 1. So that we can keep both in the final output. You can remove expression to check it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(x = c(23,23,23,23,15,15,15,17,17,78,78,78),
                 y = c(1,4,56,59,89,12,15,18,21,11,38,41),
                 z = c(1,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2))

df %>%
   filter(!(z == 1 & lead(z) != 2))
```